# Woocommerce PHP site that shows table with orders from specific category

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, mysql

i want to make a PHP site for each of my deliverer that shows orders for them, im using querry like this to show orders:

```
select
    p.ID as order_id,
    p.post_date,
    max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_billing_email' and p.ID = pm.post_id THEN pm.meta_value END ) as Mail,
    max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_billing_first_name' and p.ID = pm.post_id THEN pm.meta_value END ) as Imie,
    max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_billing_last_name' and p.ID = pm.post_id THEN pm.meta_value END ) as Nazwisko,
    max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_billing_postcode' and p.ID = pm.post_id THEN pm.meta_value END ) as KodPocztowy,
    max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_shipping_first_name' and p.ID = pm.post_id THEN pm.meta_value END ) as Imie,
    max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_shipping_last_name' and p.ID = pm.post_id THEN pm.meta_value END ) as Nazwisko,
    max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_order_total' and p.ID = pm.post_id THEN pm.meta_value END ) as Suma,
    max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_paid_date' and p.ID = pm.post_id THEN pm.meta_value END ) as Zaplacono,
    ( select group_concat( order_item_name separator '|' ) from wp_woocommerce_order_items where order_id = p.ID ) as Zamowiono
from
    wp_posts as p,
    wp_postmeta as pm
where
    post_type = 'shop_order' and
    p.ID = pm.post_id and
    post_date BETWEEN '2020-01-01' AND '2021-07-08'
group by
    p.ID
```

And i use this querry to show my categories

```
SELECT wp_terms.term_id,wp_terms.name 
FROM wp_terms 
LEFT JOIN wp_term_taxonomy 
ON wp_terms.term_id = wp_term_taxonomy.term_id 
WHERE wp_term_taxonomy.taxonomy = 'product_cat'
```

how can i join those two querries to show orders only from specific category like clothes etc?